# list of dict-like strings to one dictionary

Tags: python

```
s=['Closure Type: Button', 'Fit: Regular', 'Neckline: Collar Neck', 
   'Sleeve Length: Long Sleeve', 'Sleeve Style: Cuffed Sleeve']
```

Hello, I am trying to convert the above list to one dictionary

The keys are not constant to all the strings I need to change.

I tried

```
data={{k:v} for i in s for k,v in i.split(': ')}
json.loads(s)
```

but I get

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

my expected output is :

```
data={'Closure Type':'Button','Fit':'Regular','Neckline':'Collar Neck',
      'Sleeve Length':'Long Sleeve','Sleeve Style':'Cuffed Sleeve'}
```

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: @shahaf one dictionary

Comment: @shahaf I added to question

Comment: @PatrickArtner `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the [data structures page of python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html): "The dict() constructor builds dictionaries directly from sequences of key-value pairs".

So this works:

```
dict(i.split(": ") for i in s)
```

Comment: thanks,it works.
I use python 3.7.3 will this keep the order as it is in the list?

Comment: Perhaps you better use [```collections.OrderedDict```](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: @accdias It doesn't really matter, but I just wonder since python3.7.3 "holds" the order

Comment: Indeed it does. I don't remember in which version that was implemented though. :-(

Comment: And here is the answer: Python 3.6 via [PEP 468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/).